# How to pushback a variable of a struct into a vector

Tags: c++

```
struct Point
{
    int row,
        col;
};

struct Ship
{
    string name;
    int size;
    int hitcount;
    vector <Point> cell;
};

struct PlayerBoard
{
    char player[10][10];
    Ship shipinfo[FLEET_SIZE];  
};
```

Say I'm trying to do something like this inside a loop, Board is of type PlayerBoard

```
Board.shipinfo[i].cell.row.push_back(5);
```

it gives me no member named row. How would I go about push backing into the empty vector of cell with the variables row and col?

Comment: a `std::vector` has no `row`. Please include a [mcve] and the error message you get

Comment: `Board.shipinfo[i].cell.emplace_back(51, 42);` ?

Comment: You can push a `Point` instance into the `cell` vector. Is that what you want to do? What is the actual problem that you try to solve?

Comment: OT: unless you have a fixed size grid of 10x10 players represented by a single character I would strongly suggest to choose a more appropriate type (perhaps a `std::vector<std::string>>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your call and structure following could work

```
Board.shipinginfo[i].cell.emplace_back(1 /*row*/, 2 /*col*/);
```

You tried to **push_back** onto a integer... which can't work. `cell` is the vector you may try to do so.